# How to convert the contents of a `div` to a string

Tags: jquery

```
$.each($('#div'),function(index,element){
  console.log(element);
});
```

The output in `element` is a`div` containing several `<p>`. How to turn this content into a string?

Comment: Take care about the `#div` repeating... it should be a `class`

Comment: `$.each($(selector), ...)` should be `$(selector).each(...)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change this:
`$.each($('#div')`

to

`$.each($('div')`

The $.each is used to iterate over a series of something (bullets, divs etc)  giving it an ID suggest that it will only iterate once or you have made an error because more than one elements has the same id.

So this might work:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
      $(function(){
           $.each($('div'),function(e){
                console.log($(this).html());
           });
      })

 </script>
 <body>
 <div> content 1 </div>
 <div> content 2 </div>
 <div> content 3 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn them all into a single string, you can use `map()`.

```js
var contents = $('div').map(function(){ return this.innerHTML; }).get().join('');

console.log(contents);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><p>Content 1</p></div>
<div><p>Content 2</p></div>
<div><p>Content 3</p></div>
<div><p>Content 4</p></div>
<div><p>Content 5</p></div>
```